# Why python and whereis python return different value?

Tags: python, homebrew

I am using MAC Serria and having python 2.7.10 (/usr/bin/python) installed by default by Apple, cannot remove it. So I am going to install 2.7.15 to use it with Robot framework.

Here is the steps:

1. `brew install python@2`
2. `whereis python`

   => /usr/bin/python
3. `which python`

   => /usr/local/bin/python

Trying enter command "python" in terminal, the python 2.7.15 console is displaying.

I am not sure that because the returned values of two command lines are not the same as, which causing the problem that Eclipse IDE/InteliJ cannot find python Intepreter.

/.bash_profile

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/userName/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
```

Could you please share your ideas.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/40301/475508

Comment: By the way, `pyenv` can be installed with brew. https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Answer (score 1):

They don't search in the same place.

`whereis` searches the standard *nix locations, while `which` searches your user-specific PATH. Some locations can overlap, but it is normal to have them find different results.

If you type `python` the shell will search the PATH, so `which` is the correct command to find out which python is being executed when you type `python`.

Comment: How can I make both of the value are the same as ?

Comment: They're not supposed to be the same. It is normal that they have different values.